# Git pull from several repos in one command

Tags: git, synchronization, merge

I'd like to keep Git repositories on four machines synchronized, and all of them are private repos. Is it possible to set up a single Git repository to pull from the other three machines at the same time, with all the changes attempting to merge with a single branch locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git remote update
```

will pull from all of your remotes.  The merge won't be automatic.  You could try

```
git merge -s octopus r1/master r2/master r3/master r4/master
```

to get a five-way octopus merge, but it doesn't seem like that's what you'd really want (I certainly wouldn't want that).

Comment: All remotes unless `remotes.default` is not defined, in which case `git remote update` would fetch from all remotes in group specified by 'remotes.default'.  If 'remotes.default' is not defined, it would nevertheless skip remotes for which `remote.<name>.skipDefaultUpdate` config variable is true.  See http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html